# How do I tell my girlfriend to stop guilting me that I don't love her enough?

Tags: relationships, conflict-aversion, romance

My girlfriend and I have been together for several months and recently moved in with each other. She moved into my apartment. I have a high-paying job, in fact, I make quite a bit more than her, and the apartment we live in is way under the budget I could afford. Because of this, I decided to continue paying all of the bills when she moved in. She's offered to help, but I refuse because it would be hard for her financially and it's not a burden for me to just continue paying on my own.

Lately, she's been saying that I don't love her enough or that she loves me more. I've been compared to her exes a couple of times and also compared to how my own friend treats his girlfriend. This is all concerning to me because I can't believe she would ever think I don't love her. I've bought her expensive gifts for Valentine's day and her birthday. When she is studying for school I have to stay up much later than I should have to help her when I needed to work in the morning. On top of everything, she knows I was reluctant to let her move in but decided to do it anyway because it was most convenient for her job. I thought it was too soon, but she really wanted to because it's much closer to a good job that recently hired her.

**How can I tell her that I don't like feeling guilty when she says I don't love her enough?** I'd like to just tell her that it makes me feel guilty and to please stop, but I know what her response will be. She will most likely say that I'm taking her words "too seriously" or she may just say "fine" then go silent. The latter I consider another guilt trip technique.

Comment: Does she cite anything specific that you do or don't say/do when telling you that she thinks you don't love her enough? Or is that all she says?

Comment: @scohe001 She said she just "feels it". Once I walked into our apartment from work and didn't kiss her (2 min max) so she pointed it out. I immediately kissed her after she mentioned it, but she brought it up later as an example. She also brought up the fact that my friend posted a confession of his love to his gf on Facebook, but I've never did that for her.

Comment: As a comment that is not directly related, if she genuinely offers to help with the bills, then let her. It is a dignity issue, nobody wants to be a freeloader. If you want to partition them, so that she pays the same *fraction* of the bills as her fraction of income is to yours, that is usually a nice compromise.

Answer (score 30):

From what it looks like, it seems like your girlfriend doesn't feel particularly loved and understood. If this is happening there's something she likely expects from you, but it's hard to know what that might be isn't it?

There's a particular concept that really comes to mind from this and past experiences, known as [The Five Love Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Five_Love_Languages). This describes the expectations of how two individuals expect to have affection/love communicated. It doesn't only apply to romance too, its uses extend beyond those types of relationships.

What it really tackles is figuring out what someone needs from you or what you need from someone else. The five languages are defined as the following:

- Receiving gifts
- Quality time
- Affirmative words
- Acts of service
- Physical contact

Often times conflict and lack of feelings of love arrive from simply not understanding how your partner observes it. You need to figure out how **both** of you expect to receive love communication. Once you do that, you'll be able to balance your relationship and understand your partner a lot better. You'll know how they expect to feel loved and better serve that need.

From the comment you left, she was upset you didn't kiss her when you got home. She could expect "Physical Contact" as a language and having a kiss when you get home is something that's important to her.

Have a discussion with her about these love languages and ask her what's important to her and what makes her feel loved. You will no longer have the need to actually tell her to stop guilting you because you won't feel guilty anymore (since you know what she wants you to do). By fixing the root problem, you will remove the undesired side-effects. :)

Comment: to your examples, you might want to add that OP mentions he gives her (expensive) gifts and expects that to confirm his love for her, while she might not really care as much about the gifts as he thinks.

Answer (score 0):

@anilla has an excellent answer that takes one possibility into account.  I'd propose that there's also another, less wholesome, possible motive.

I've had a couple people in my life who were manipulative and this should be explored as well.  The behaviors you write about are similar to those that I've experienced with attempts at emotional manipulation.

Those relationships always centered around trying to get me to do something or to do more of something.  Seldom would the other party clearly say what they wanted; they would drop all kinds of hints, make comparisons to others, or even say "If you really loved me/cared about me/cared/were a part of this, you'd..."  And of course, when confronted about this behavior, the response was denial "no, I'm not trying to use guilt to do X.."  (Note: studying educational psychology was part of my college major so I had some tools to look at this.  Don't go first-year psych student on people..)

In that case, the only way I could find to deal with that behavior was to call the bluff.  "Interesting about that couple.  Oh, well!"  "Oh?  That's wild"  "Do you think I don't care?  Is that what you're saying?"  "Well maybe you do love me more"  The important thing about calling a bluff is that you have to be ready to deal with and accept the consequences.